# Как записать в разные колонки в csv формате?

Tags: python, selenium, csv

Есть код, который парсит сайт и надо записать спаршенную информацию в csv формат в колонки, как это можно реализовать?

```
 from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException as TE
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import csv


def get_url(driver): # перехожу по урлу на нужный сайт
    driver.get('https://www.avvo.com/topics/landlord-tenant-law/advice?order=recency&page=1&search_topic_advice_search[content_type]=Q%26A&search_topic_advice_search[query]=security+deposit&search_topic_advice_search[state]=CA')
    time.sleep(3)


def get_content(driver): # собираю информация со страницы
    try:
        span = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12']/div[@id='qa-body-display']/p[@class='a button btn btn-link u-vertical-padding-0']/span[@class='icon-chevron-down-after-blue']").click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        mores_lawyer = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12']/button[@class='btn btn-link u-vertical-padding-0']")
        for more_lawyer in mores_lawyer:
            more_lawyer.click()
            time.sleep(1)
    except:
        pass

    question_short = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@itemprop='name']")
    question_long = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@itemprop='text']")
    date_question_posts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12']/ul[@class='inline-list']/li[@class='text-muted small hidden-xs']")
    name_lawyers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']")
    lawyer_answers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@itemprop='text']")
    dates = []
    names = []
    answers = []
    for lawyer_answer in lawyer_answers:
        answers.append(lawyer_answer.text)
    for date_question_post in date_question_posts:
        dates.append(date_question_post.text)
    for name_lawyer in name_lawyers:
        names.append(name_lawyer.text)

    with open("data.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)

        name_short = question_short.text
        name_long = question_long.text
        writer.writerows(name_short)
        writer.writerows(name_long)
        print("\nQuestion: ",name_short, "\n" ,name_long, "\n")
        for date in dates:
            print(date)
            writer.writerows(date)
        for name in names:
            print("\nLawyer name: ", name)
            writer.writerows(name)
        for answer in answers:
            print("\nLawyer answer: ", answer)
            writer.writerows(answer)

    # return (name_short, name_long, name_lawyer, answer, date_question_post)


def page_pagination(driver):
    divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-2']/a[@class='block-link']")
    urls = []
    for div in divs:
        url = div.get_attribute("href")
        urls.append(url)
    for url_1 in urls:
        trans = driver.get(url_1)
        time.sleep(2)
        get_content(driver)
        time.sleep(1)


def main():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    get_url(driver)
    page_pagination(driver)

    driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

P.S пытался записать, но всё писалось в один столбец

Comment: В вашем коде нет и намёка на запись CSV.

Comment: a сейчас? Я не вставлял так как это слишком ужасно

Comment: Могу предложить сохранять данные в виде словаря и потом словарём записывать в csv, мне кажется так проще, а вообще, если вам csv нужен просто для хранения информации, то вероятно лучшим средством будет хранение инфы в sql базе данных, а точнее во встроенной в Python SQLite. Сам когда начинал думал про хранение в csv, но хорошо что на sql перешёл))

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

for row in in zip_longest(dates, names, answers):
    print(*row)
    writer.writerows(row)
```

Comment: выбивает ошибку writer.writerows(row)
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not NoneType

Comment: Это странно. Ошибка означает, что в переменной цикла `row` содержится `None`, но функция `zip_longest` не может вернуть `None`.

Comment: 1 пост парсит почти нормально, а вот перейдя на второй возбужает ошибку

Comment: + ставит запятую после каждого символа

Comment: Значит у вас не всегда в переменных `dates`, `names` и `answers` содержатся списки.